# Chime SDK Video not responsive

Tags: reactjs, aws-chime-sdk

I have built a react.js client app that interfaces with the Chime SDK and some REST APIs. It creates a meeting, an attendee, connects the local hardware and starts the audio & video.

My issue is that the video is a fixed size.

It is within a React Bootsrap responsive layout as follows:

```
<Container fluid style={containerStyle}>
    <Row>
        <Col sm="10">
            <audio id="my-audio-element"></audio>
            <video id="my-video-element"></video>
        </Col>
        <Col sm="2">
            ...
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Container>
```

The `<audio id="my-audio-element"></audio>` and `<video id="my-video-element"></video>` elements are as advised by the SDK documentation. The parent `<Col sm="10">` is responsive.

Whatever i do to the page the Chime video remains a fixed size?

**UPDATE**

Setting `class="h-100 w-100"` enables the video to resize, however, it still has a fixed aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the SDK demo/browser app:

```
.video-tile-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```